# Get functions called in a Python expression

Tags: python

I have a database that holds the name of Python functions and a string for their code. I want the user to be able to enter a Python code and see the result. The problem is that I need to know the names of the functions they call in order to retrieve the code from the database. For instance, if they enter `cubic_fit(1, 2, get_data())`, I need a way to get the function names `cubic_fit` and `get_data`. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: you might need to use a decorator in order to grab the function name... but there might be an easier way which I don't know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in function [compile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile) will do that for you exactly:

```
>>> compile("cubic_fit(1, 2, get_data())", '<string>', 'eval').co_names
('cubic_fit', 'get_data')
```

And it is safe to run. No code is actually being executed just compiled.

Comment: @Nadia Alramli  [In passing], Congrats for passing the 10k reps mark in speedy time! I often find your responses to the point and useful (and, unfortunately, you often beat me to it ;-) )  Keep up the good work!

Comment: @mjv, thanks! You are faster that me for sure: 8,079 in 2 month wow! :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick example to you started. Note that you'll be expecting valid python semantics for this to work.

You can extend this to also parse your arguments...

```
import token, tokenize, StringIO

def extract_names(src):
    rawstr = StringIO.StringIO(unicode(src))
    tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(rawstr.readline)
    for i, item in enumerate(tokens):
        toktype, toktext, (srow,scol), (erow,ecol), line = item
        if token.tok_name[toktype] == 'NAME':
            print 'name:', toktext

extract_names("cubic_fit(1, 2, get_data())")

# --> output:
# name: cubic_fit
# name: get_data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the names, then the compile() and co_names method will work best.

You also might take advantage of the capability of eval() to use any mapping object as its locals parameter.  You could create a mapping object to look up and compile the objects from your database as needed by eval().

Example:

```
class LookitUp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # simulate some data
        self.d = { "foo": "def foo(a):\n  return a + 2"}

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        localdict = {}
        c = compile(self.d.get(key,""),"<string>","exec")
        eval(c,globals(),localdict)
        return localdict[key]

d = LookitUp()

def bar(a): 
    return a - 1

print "foo from database :",eval("foo(3)",globals(), d)
print "bar from globals():",eval("bar(3)",globals(), d)
print "foo(bar(3))       :",eval("foo(bar(3))",globals(), d)
```

Result:

```
foo from database : 5
bar from globals(): 2
foo(bar(3))       : 4
```

You may need to modify based on what your source in the database looks like, but it's a place to start.

Comment: That's more or less what I'm planning to do :)